# How to reimplement triggered() signal in pyqt for a QAction?

Tags: python, plugins, pyqt, signals-slots, qaction

I'm using Python with PyQt, for my interface, and Yapsi, for add plugins. Yapsy found all my plugins and add all to a menu in my mainWindow. Each plugin, is activated with triggered signal. This signal for a QAction don't have params and I need know what plugin was emit the signal.

This is the relevant code:

```
pluginMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("P&lugins")

# Create plugin manager
self.manager = PluginManager(categories_filter={ "Formatters": Formatter})
self.manager.setPluginPlaces(["plugins"])

# Load plugins
self.manager.locatePlugins()
self.manager.loadPlugins()

# A do-nothing formatter by default
self.formatters = {}

for plugin in self.manager.getPluginsOfCategory("Formatters"):

# plugin.plugin_object is an instance of the plugin
print(plugin.plugin_object.name)
# The method to create action associated each input to default triggered() signal
newAction = self.createAction(plugin.plugin_object.name, slot=self.updatePreview())


self.addActions(pluginMenu, (newAction, None))
self.formatters[plugin.plugin_object.name] = (plugin.plugin_object, newAction)

def updatePreview(self):
    # Here I need know what plugin emit the signal    
    #===================================================================
```

I thought to conect the signal with other signal with some params but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's Yapsi, but there is [`QObject.sender`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qobject.html#sender) method:

> **QObject QObject.sender (self)**
>
> Returns a pointer to the object that sent the signal, if called in a
>   slot activated by a signal; otherwise it returns 0. The pointer is
>   valid only during the execution of the slot that calls this function
>   from this object's thread context.
>
> The pointer returned by this function becomes invalid if the sender is
>   destroyed, or if the slot is disconnected from the sender's signal.
>
> Warning: This function violates the object-oriented principle of
>   modularity. However, getting access to the sender might be useful when
>   many signals are connected to a single slot.
>
> Warning: As mentioned above, the return value of this function is not
>   valid when the slot is called via a Qt.DirectConnection from a thread
>   different from this object's thread. Do not use this function in this
>   type of scenario.

Some more tips here: http://blog.odnous.net/2011/06/frequently-overlooked-and-practical.html

Comment: Yapsy is a simple library for add new plugins. It's good for make your software more modular.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is with a [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qsignalmapper.html).

Example code:

```
signalmap = QSignalMapper(self)
signalmap.mapped[QString].connect(self.handler)
...
signalmap.setMapping(action, name)
action.triggered[()].connect(signalmap.map)
```

This will re-emit the `triggered` signal with a string "name" parameter. It's also possible to re-emit signals with an `int`, `QWidget` or `QObject` parameter.